# How to make a select case non-blocking in for loop without default

Tags: go, channel, select-case

I have this piece of code.

```
func Start() bool {
    for {
        if checkSomthingIsTrue() {
            if err := doSomthing(); err != nil {
                continue
            }
        }
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

How to make the above function non blocking without using `default:` case.
reason to not use default case is because its eating up 100% CPU always.

Answer:
I have used time.Ticker to throttle
Thanks

Comment: `select` blocks if none of the communication ops are ready to proceed. You can only make a `select` without `default` non-blocking if you ensure at least one of its comm ops can proceed.

Comment: If you don't want a `default` because it "eats up" your CPU, then it looks you don't want `checkSomthingIsTrue()` to be called continuously. Use a `time.Timer` or `time.Ticker` to achieve some "sleep" between iterations, and still monitor the context while sleeping.

Comment: If you don't want a loop to use 100% CPU you want it to block. Can you explain how you want a non-blocking statement to block?

Comment: There is a literal answer, but it's useless: just make sure one of the channels you select on is always ready. For instance, add a closed channel to the list of channels. But then you'll use 100% CPU on the closed channel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a fundamental misunderstanding here. A thread can do only two things:

- A thread can **block,** waiting for something.
- A thread can **run,** using CPU.

If a thread never blocks, then it uses 100% of the available CPU. **You cannot make non-blocking code use less than 100% of the available CPU.**

You have three options:

1. Use non-blocking code, and accept the 100% CPU usage.
2. Redesign `checkSomthingIsTrue()` so it uses a channel, and can be put inside the `select` block.

   ```
   for {
       select {
       case <-ctx.Done():
           return true
       case <-whenSomethingIsTrue():
           if err := doSomthing(); err != nil {
               continue
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use a timeout to throttle the loop, for example:

   ```
   // Poll every 100ms.
   const pollInterval = 100 * time.Millisecond
   for {
       select {
       case <-ctx.Done():
           return true
       case <-time.After(pollInterval):
           if checkSomthingIsTrue() {
               if err := doSomthing(); err != nil {
                   continue
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Also note that `continue` makes no sense, but that is a different issue.

Comment: we can use [time.Tikcer](https://gobyexample.com/tickers) instead of `time.After` right?

Comment: @nipuna: Sure, if you prefer, you can use `Ticker`. The timing will be different.

Comment: You can use a `time.Ticker` but you may need to call Stop() on it when you are done otherwise you may leak tickers.`time.After()` cleans itself up after the duration. A `time.Timer` will be the same as `time.After()` for timing but you control when it is cleaned up.